# How to prevent for loop from starting next iteration until the function inside it (AWS S3 upload function) to fully complete?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a set of images to aws s3 bucket and show their progress one by one in progress bar.In the code bellow present_images_array is the array of image data values.My sample code is given bellow

```
function uploadImgValToItems(img){
 var bar = $('.progress-bar');
 var percent = $('.percent');
 var status = $('#status');
 var blobData = dataURItoBlob(img);
 var albumPhotosKey = 'uploads/' + encodeURIComponent("items") + '/';
 var photo_id = uuidv4();
 var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + photo_id+".jpeg";

 s3.upload({
  Key: photoKey,
  Body: blobData,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  ACL: 'public-read'
 }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
  main_image_size = evt.total;
  per = parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total);
  bar.width(per+"%")
  bar.attr("aria-valuenow",per);
  bar.html(per+"%");
  status.html("Uploading ");
  status.show();
  console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / 
  evt.total)+'%');

 }).send(function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
   alert("error occured"}
  }else{
   alert("upload completed successfully")
  }
 });
 }
```

when i call this function inside for loop

```
for (img of present_images_array){
  uploadImgValToItems(img); 
}
```

I want first image to upload completely then the next image is uploaded, that way. But what actually happens is that images are uploaded asynchronously. How to make the for loop to wait until the function completes.?

Comment: You could have `uploadImgValToItems` return a `Promise` and then `await` each call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `send()` which takes a callback, you could use `.promise()` which returns a Promise that you can work with, and you can `await` that promise in the loop. For that you have to return the promise:

```
const upload = s3.upload({
  Key: photoKey,
  Body: blobData,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  ACL: 'public-read'
});

upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
    //...
});

return upload.promise(); // <---
```

So now you can simply `await`, but for that the loop must be inside of an async function that returns a promise utself:

```
(async function() {      
   for (const img of present_images_array){
     await uploadImgValToItems(img); 
   }
})();
```